What are examples of trustworthy no-fees open access scientific journals where serious scientists have published?
I sometimes hear the claim there are no no-fee open access journals available in some fields. An example on this website was recently for the case of Bio Informatics / Computational Biology.
What are examples of trustworthy no-fees open access scientific journals where serious scientists have published for different fields? Can we list at least one such a journal for each "field"? (A community answer would probably be best.)
To start things of does someone know a no-fee open access journal in Bio Informatics / Computational Biology?

I think SciPost Biology counts except for "where serious scientists have published" it seems it has zero publications so far...
Seems the web developer is outpacing the actual publishing and this journal doesn't actually exist / allow submission yet.

Example answer for Theoretical Physics:
In theoretical physics Scipost Physics (https://scipost.org/SciPostPhys) does qualify. Even some quite renowned physicists have published there.

About this being a shopping question. Perhaps. If people prefer this to be closed I'll ask elsewhere on the internet. I very much think this would be a great resource to have to point people to at least one open access free journal in each field. Note that the criteria are objective. And I'm not looking for the best. Just for at least one example of a no-fees open access scientific journal for every field. Perhaps I should expand on serious scientists just meaning scientists with academic affiliations. I wanted to weed out crackpot journals or journals without actual publications.

SciPost Physics is not restricted to theory, it just seems experimentalists often prefer other journals.

Feels like a classic shopping question: https://academia.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3657/why-was-my-question-put-on-hold-for-shopping

@user176372 If it it intended to make a big list of these journals in all major fields, then that seems like not a shopping question. If the intent is to just get a journal meeting their specific needs in a specific field, then it is a shopping question. Not clear to me what intent/setup was. I interpreted it the first way.

@JoshuaZ What pushes me over is the request for "serious scientists" having published. Too much opinion. I really don't think this format works for producing big lists of links.

@user176372 Hmm. I agree that "serious scientists" may be too opinion/subjective.  It doesn't seem though like a bad format for producing a lot of links. But those seem like issues distinct from whether this is shopping.

@JoshuaZ Lists are also explicitly disallowed in the close reason for shopping questions.

Journal of Fish and Wildlife Management and the https://www.theoj.org/ publish 4 and are all open access and free for everyone to submit or read

@BryanKrause Ah, good point. I forgot that.

@RichardErickson, thanks for the suggestions!

BTW, for anyone who had more suggestions. Closed or not I'm interested in the answer. I added the question and answer to my profile (including a way to contact me) which I believe to is allowed (see https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/31505/377032).

I think expanding "serious scientists" to "scientists with academic affiliations" makes it less opinionated, but also much too broad.

Honestly I'd be fine with leaving that constraint out completely. I just hope not to get a list filled with "journals" that are no more than a way to pretend that you have published something. I guess most of those are pay to publish anyway so perhaps the constraint is not important.

In mathematics there are a lot of them. Two that come immediately to mind are Integers, and the Journal of Integer Sequences. Both have a number theory/combinatorics sort of focus. They aren't high prestige (as evidence by the fact that I've published in them) but they are definitely trustworthy.
A few others include Communications of the AMS (seems to on the higher prestige end). Rather than go through and list more, I'll just note that there are a lot of others, and this Mathoverflow question has a bunch although some of those there may have changed their access models since people included them. From that list, it looks like they are more common in pure math than in applied math, but that may be due to Mathoverflow running more on the pure than applied end for active users.
